# Changing text inside span after click (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I have button inside span

```
<span class="act-button"><input type="button" value="Deactivate" onclick="deactivateTemplate(' + options.rowId + ')"></span>
```

and I need to change text inside `span.act-button` after `onclick`,
I tried to use this code

```
function deactivateTemplate(id) {
        $.post('@Url.Action("DeactivateFormTemplate")', { id: id })
        .done(function (result) {
            showMessage(result.Message);
            $('span.act-button').empty().html('<input type="button" value="Activate" onclick="activateTemplate(' + options.rowId + ')">');
        });
```

but after click my button just disappears and I don't get new button inside `span.act-button`.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Almost every line of this code is referencing something we can't see.  Are you sure it's all working together as you expect it to?  What are the resulting values from these references?  When you debug this, at what point does the observed behavior deviate from the expected behavior?

Comment: I get `<span class="act-button"><input type="button" value="Deactivate" onclick="deactivateTemplate(' + options.rowId + ')"></span>` on my page, but after click `span.act-button` becomes empty and I don't get a new button inside.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not necessary to recreate your button. Just change its value

   ```
   function deactivateTemplate(id) {
           $.post('@Url.Action("DeactivateFormTemplate")', { id: id })
           .done(function (result) {
               showMessage(result.Message);
               $('span.act-button>input').val('Activate');
           });
   }
   ```
2. DOM manipulation methods in jquery are asynchronous: they don't complete immediately. So it is possible for empty() to complete executing after html(). Try not to use both like that.